# Identify surface mount capacitor: marked 29 newline 47 newline 16C newline + dark half-moon

Tags: identification, surface-mount

This is most likely a 47uF and 16V capacitor, but I need exact dimensions, temperature limits, ripple, ESR and MTBF (hours) specs. So I am looking for the manufacturer and exact part number. Any ideas? Thanks! [image: Small silver-colored capacitor about wlh=776 mm and marked 29 newline 47 newline 16C newline + dark half-moon]

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a [SunCon 16CE47PC](https://www.sunelec.co.jp/common/pdf/eng/CE-PC.pdf).

[image]

I couldn't find a picture of this exact capacitor, but here is one from the same manufacturer's KX series (series symbol "K"). The marking style looks very similar.

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Aluminum-Electrolytic-Capacitors-SMD_SUNCON-SUN-Elec-Industries-63CE47KX_C242088.html))